# Index and Match Multiple Criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, criteria

I have two tables of data with the same columns. The first is populated with experimental data:

```
`Treatment  Species TimeofDay   Temp    Light   X
     M        B       AM         25      25     2
     M        B       PM         26      50     3
     M        B       PM         27      150    4
     M        C       AM         25      25     5
     M        C       AM         26      150    6
     M        C       PM         27      500    7
     M        C       PM         28      800    9
     A        B       AM         25       25    2
     A        B       PM         26       50    3
     A        B       PM         27       150   4
     A        C       AM         25       25    5
     A        C       AM         26      150    6
     A        C       PM         27      500    7
     A        C       PM         28      800    9
```

In the second table I   want to fill in the "X" column with values from the first table so that in the given row A) all of the categorical values match exactly those from table one AND B) Temp and Light values are closest (but won't be exact) to matching values in table 1.

For example, if in Table 2 I have:

```
Treatment  Species  TimeofDay  Temp  Light  X
    M         B        PM       30    200
```

I would want the function to give me 4 in the X column.
I am familiar with indexing a value in one column given a match in another and with finding a closest matching value in a column, but I am having trouble putting all these criteria together:

```
=INDEX(Table1!F$2:F$20,
MATCH(Table2!A$2,Table1!A$2:A$20,0))
MATCH(Table2!B$2,Table1!B$2:B$20,0))
MATCH(Table2!C$2,Table1!C$2:C$20,0))
MATCH(MIN(ABS(Table1!D$2:D$20-Table2!D$2)),ABS(Table1!D$2:D$20-Table2!D$2), 0))
MATCH(MIN(ABS(Table1!E$2:E$20-Table2!E$2)),ABS(Table1!E$2:E$20-Table2!E$2),0))
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What index do you want to return when combining these for multiple criteria? the F column range, or D column range?  If you want to return the F range, I think you can use this (Enter as an array, with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER): `=INDEX(Table1!F$1:F20,MATCH(Table2!D$1&MIN(ABS(Table1!D$1:D$20-Table2!D$1)),Table1!D$1:D$20&ABS(Table1!D$1:D$20-Table2!D$1),0))`.

Comment: Could you provide some mockup data so we do not need to try and recreate tables that may or may not be like yours?

Comment: Here's a (hopefully) simple example of how to match multiple conditions.  Say I have FirstNames in column B, LastNames in column C, and want to return the ID# in Column A. I want to match a first name in `F1` and a lastname in `G1`, and return the ID. I'd use this in `G3`: `=Index(A:A,match(F1&G1,B:B&C:C,0))`, entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.  You just connect the "conditions" with `&`, and do the same with their ranges.

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne, I think I am getting closer. This is what I have right now which gets me an answer, but it doesn't seem to be the right one. I used a 1 at the end instead of a 0 because the numerical matches won't be exact.         =INDEX(Table1!F$2:F$6247,MATCH(Table2!A$2&Table2!B$2&Table2!C$2&Table2!D$2&Table2!E$2,Table1!A$2:A$6247&Table1!B$2:B$6247&Table1!C$2:C$6247&(MIN(ABS(Table1!D$2:D$6247-Table2!D$2)))&(MIN(ABS(Table1!E$2:E$6247-Table2!E$2))),1))

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner. I have edited the question with a simplified example of the table and issue.

Comment: I have been looking into it.  It may be beyond me as a formula.  I would look into vba and writing a UDF.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @ScottCraner.
Thinking about it more...if I am looking for the closest match in two separate instances (both column Temp and Light) will the order of these in the function set their priorities? So if there are two answers, one where the closest Temp match is off by 3 and the Light off by 7 and one where its switched, which one will the index give back?

Comment: (Can you add any additional attempts/formulas in your OP? Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula is working, put in F2:

```
=INDEX(Table1!F:F,MATCH(MIN(IF(A2=Table1!A:A,IF(B2 = Table1!B:B,IF(C2 = Table1!C:C,ABS((Table1!D:D+Table1!E:E)-(D2+E2)))))),IF(A2=Table1!A:A,IF(B2 = Table1!B:B,IF(C2 = Table1!C:C,ABS((Table1!D:D+Table1!E:E)-(D2+E2))))),0))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  Then copy down.

As to your other comment the priority if the difference is the same will be the first in order.

Comment: AWESOME! As far as I can tell so far it is working on my super complex spreadsheet as well. Thank you again for all of your effort.